# R-squared: Panel Data Regression

Tags: regression, panel-data, stata

I have a question about $ R^2$ is panel data regression. Let's suppose that I estimate the following model by random effects:

$$ y_{it} =  \alpha + \beta x+u_i+\epsilon_{it} $$

Then, by assumption, the overall $ R^2 $ is given by:

$$ R^2=\frac{Var(\hat{\beta} x)+Var(\hat{u}_i)}{Var(y_{it})} $$

My question is, how do I find the following augmented $ R^2$?:

$$ S^2=\frac{Var(\hat{\beta} x)}{Var(y_{it})} $$

In particular, is this value related to the *sigma_u* and *rho* values reported by STATA?

That is, would I take the overall $ R^2$, then subtract $ \frac{\text{sigma_u}^2}{Var(y_{it})}$?